# How to remove or change "height" at element.style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm marking some image page with figure&figcaption which is sort of gallery slider.

But the height size is all of same automatically in element style figure img, figcaption img as well when I saw the code in Chrome developer tools.

I think I need to change this code.

```js
 for( var i = 0; i < wall.itemsCount; ++i ) {

    var $item = wall.$items.eq( i );

    $item.appendTo( $wallElem );

    var itemH = $item.height(),
     figcaptionH = $item.find( 'figcaption' ).outerHeight( true );

    if( itemH > wallH - wallmargins ) {
     $item.find('img').height( wallH - wallmargins - figcaptionH );
     $item.css( 'top', ( wallmargins / 2 ));
    }
    else {
     $item.css( 'top', ( wallH - itemH ) / 2 );
    }
```

please give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the height for only `figcaption img`, then update your selector to include that

```
$item.find('figcaption img').height(wallH - wallmargins - figcaptionH);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.

I changed the code as you wrote.

but I don't want to change figure size. It has to same size.




http://tympanus.net/Development/3DGalleryRoom/

I'm doing it